# One signal not working on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onesignal

I have created a extension news feed app and am having trouble. Onesignal notification does not work. I use a background HTML Page in Manifest instead of a background script.

Manifest File:

```js
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "New Feed",
    "description": "The extension for Google Chrome",
"icons": {
        "128": "img/icon-128.png",
        "16": "img/icon-16.png",
        "48": "img/icon-48.png"
    },
    "version": "1.1",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "storage",
        "alarms",
        "notifications",
        "*://*/*",
           "gcm",
        "storage",
        "notifications",
        "identity" 
    ],

    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
      },
```

Background Page:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sha1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onesignal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onesignalBg.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

OnesignalBg File:

```js
OneSignal.init({appId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
                googleProjectNumber: "xxxxxxxxxx"});
```

Comment: Your best friend is devtools: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Comment: @wOxxOm not work even i closed it with Closing script

Comment: @wOxxOm i update the code check it.